# SQL Server : creating a top 3 view - having difficulties

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my first time asking a SQL related question. I am having a difficult time getting this query to work.

Basically, I have a database that has 3 tables `Course`, `Faculty` and `Adjunct`. This query is supposed to create a view named `Top3Enrollment` that returns `FirstName, LastName, TotalStudents`, and `MaxEnrollment` of the 3 faculty members with the largest total enrollment for their courses, along with the highest enrollment among the classes they teach.

When attempting to write the query I get an error with selecting the column `FirstName`

My query:

```
CREATE VIEW Top3Enrollment
AS
    SELECT TOP 3 PERCENT 
        FirstName, LastName, SUM(Enrollment), MAX(Enrollment)
    FROM 
        Faculty 
    JOIN 
        Course ON Faculty.Faculty_ID = Course.Faculty_ID
    ORDER BY 
        MAX(Enrollment);
```

The error I get is:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Top3Enrollment, Line 3 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Column 'Faculty.FirstName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

My database structures:

```
CREATE TABLE Faculty
(
    Faculty_ID VARCHAR(2), 
    LastName VARCHAR(20), 
    FirstName VARCHAR(20), 
    Department VARCHAR(10), 
    Campus VARCHAR(10)
); 

INSERT INTO Faculty 
VALUES ('1', 'Brown', 'Joe', 'Business', 'Kent'),
       ('2', 'Smith', 'John', 'Economics', 'Kent'),
       ('3', 'Jones', 'Sally', 'English', 'South'),
       ('4', 'Black', 'Bill', 'Economics', 'Deerwood'),
       ('5', 'Green', 'Gene', 'Business', 'South'); 

CREATE TABLE Course
(
    Course_ID CHAR(2), 
    Ref_Number CHAR(5),
    Faculty_ID VARCHAR(2),
    Term Char(1),
    BegDate SMALLDATETIME,
    Enrollment INTEGER,
    TotRev FLOAT 
); 

INSERT INTO Course 
VALUES ('1', '12345', 'a', 'A', '2016-01-08 00:00:00', 24, 12345.32 ),
       ('2', '54321', '3', 'B', '2016-02-04 00:00:00', 18, 21435.51 ),
       ('3', '13524', '1', 'B', '2016-02-04 00:00:00', 7,  1256.67 ),
       ('4', '24653', '1', 'C', '2016-03-04 00:00:00', 29, 54421.11 ),
       ('5', '98765', '5', 'A', '2016-01-08 00:00:00', 35, 246753.23),
       ('6', '14862', '2', 'B', '2016-02-04 00:00:00', 14, 9876.87),
       ('7', '96032', '1', 'C', '2016-03-04 00:00:00', 8,  863159.31),
       ('8', '81256', '5', 'A', '2016-01-08 00:00:00', 5,  98762.14),
       ('9', '64321', '2', 'C', '2016-03-04 00:00:00', 23, 2965.98),
       ('10','90908', 'a', 'A', '2016-01-08 00:00:00', 45, 91724.02),
       ('11','90908', '3', 'A', '2016-01-08 00:00:00', 23, 73725.77),
       ('12','90908', '3', 'A', '2016-01-08 00:00:00', 16, 84224.29),
       ('13','90908', 'b', 'A', '2016-01-08 00:00:00', 13, 42719.82);

CREATE TABLE Adjuncts
(
    Faculty_ID Char(2), 
    LastName VARCHAR(20), 
    FirstName VARCHAR(20), 
    Department VARCHAR(10), 
    Campus VARCHAR(10)
); 

INSERT INTO Adjuncts 
VALUES ('a', 'Rogers', 'Aaron', 'Business', 'Kent'),
       ('b', 'Manning', 'Peyton', 'Economics', 'North'),
       ('c', 'Drew', 'Maurice', 'English', 'Cecil'),
       ('d', 'Griffin', 'Robert', 'Music', 'Deerwood'),
       ('e', 'Goodell', 'Roger', 'Economics', 'South'),
       ('f', 'Vilma', 'Jonathan', 'Business', 'Kent');
```

*Note:*

I Understand I cannot have `Order By` but I wouldn't know what else to use

Added the database code

Comment: This question is impossible to answer, because there simply isn't enough information about what you have or what you want. You know what you want, but we have no idea, so you're going to have to put in a lot more detail

Comment: Ill add the database code if that helps. This is my first time posting a SQL question and didn't know how much to include.

Comment: Realistically for SQL questions: create table/insert statements for your existing real data, the full query you've written so far, and your desired output. Even better if you can create an SQL Fiddle, db<>fiddle, dbfiddle or similar and just post the link. these are websites that let you "create" a db and run a query against it. Then the pros can get straight into solving your problem rather than taking their time to write code to reproduce your db before they start writing the solution to your woes. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use aggregate functions like sum and max together with other columns you need to group your aggregations by those other columns.

Add GROUP BY like this

```
SELECT TOP 3 PERCENT FirstName, LastName, SUM(Enrollment), MAX(Enrollment)
FROM Faculty 
JOIN Course ON Faculty.Faculty_ID = Course.Faculty_ID
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
ORDER BY MAX(Enrollment);
```

Comment: Ohhh I never knew you could have a group by their! Thank you! Works now! :D